# Starting Tor after logging off then back on

Tags: 12.04, tor

After installing tor, then logging off and back on, I receive the error message:

`Warning Before Tor can create a control socket in "/var/run/tor/control", the directory "/var/run/tor" needs to exist, and to be accessible only by the user account that is running Tor`

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the directory. So open a terminal and enter the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/tor
sudo chown debian-tor:debian-tor /var/run/tor
sudo chmod 2750 /var/run/tor
```

This command creates the directory and changes the owner to `debian-tor`. The last line changes the permissions to the correct values.